# Compare the specified time and current time using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<em>2017-03-10+08:00</em>

//em                                           ->    2017-03-10+08:00
//em/codepoint-equal(., '2017-03-10+08:00')    ->    true
//em/codepoint-equal(., '')                    ->    false
//em/codepoint-equal(., current-date())        ->    ERROR!
```

How to fix error in the last case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the type mismatch error in your last case, wrap `current-date()` in `string()`,

```
//em/codepoint-equal(., string(current-date()))
```

so that the `xs:date` is explicitly converted to `xs:string` as expected by `codepoint-equal()`.

---

**Should an explicit type conversion be necessary?**

According to the [XPath 2.0 function conversion rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-function-calls),

> If, after the above conversions, the resulting value does not match the expected type according to the rules for [SequenceType   Matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-sequencetype-matching), a [type error](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-type-error) is raised [[err:XPTY0004]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPTY0004). Note that the rules for [SequenceType Matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#dt-sequencetype-matching) permit a value of a derived type to be substituted for a value of its base type.

Note the use of the word, *permit* rather than *require*.  Perhaps the XPath library that is producing an error in your last case is interpreting the function conversion rules as allowing but not requiring the conversion from `xs:date` to `xs:string`.